# Create Vue Directive that doesn't expect an expression

Tags: vue.js, pug

This code:

```
// template in pug
#review-step.container

    .panel(v-test.a)

// in main.js
Vue.directive('test', function(el, binding) {
    console.log(binding.modifiers)
})
```

Gives these errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "v" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. ...
[Vue warn]: Property or method "test" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. ...
TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined. ...
```

If I change the directive to `v-test.a=""` then it works fine. Similarly, `v-pre`, `v-cloak`, and `v-once` all work fine, so it isn't pug compiling the template incorrectly.

I want to know how to create a directive that expects no expression, like `v-pre`, `v-cloak`, or `v-b-modal` from [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal) (which by the way is the reason I'm really here, since that directive is having this same problem).

I can't find this anywhere, the [vue custom directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) docs have nothing, and searching for `directive pre` or something similar in the vue repo hasn't helped me turn up how the vue team has accomplished this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was pug. I don't know how the vue team has made their directives work regardless, but pug is [mirroring attributes](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#boolean-attributes).

Unfortunately I need to figure out how to pass the doctype option to the vue webpack loader, unless I want to declare that at the top of every template.